# insert multi post page in sitemap or not?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, google-index

i want to insert below links in Sitemap, Each page has its own unique content  :

http://poetry.qrosh.com/en/William%20Shakespeare/A%20Fairy%20Song/1/1/

so if i have multi post pages which include 10 pages:
http://poetry.qrosh.com/posts/en/William%20Shakespeare/poetry/1

can i insert multi post page in sitemap for index or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include paginated content, the best solution would be to add a [rel canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) to a view all version of the page and then submit this through your sitemap.

You will do this by adding the following link in your `<head>` section of your page. You would need to change the URL to the URL of the view all page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish"/>
```

You should also look to add [rel prev and rel next](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) to the paginated content on your website. Sometimes it can be good to have a 'category page' (so to speak) indexed, however you have to be aware of duplicate content. Each time you post a new article it will push the last article on each page to the following page. As Google won't re-index each of these pages simultaneously, you need to reduce the chance of duplicate content by only having one version indexed.